# Difference between cloning and copying in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is copying the .hg directory to another directory the same as cloning in Mercurial (using TortoiseHg although I think that's irrelevant) or does the cloning command in Mercurial do something special during that process?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's *almost* the same.  Cloning does a few things different, none of which are required, but some of which are cool:

- clones get a working directory too (which you can avoid with -U)
- clones get the source repo set as default for push/pull in the .hg/hgrc file
- clones can get just a subset of the original (clone -r X gets revision X and all ancestors only)
- clones use hardlinks when the file system supports it

That last one is pretty cool.  It means that if I have a 200GB repo and I do a `clone -U src dest` I get a full clone that uses no diskspace at all!  If I skip the `-U` I get a working copy that takes up space, and as the two clones start to diverge the new one starts taking up space, but a basic `clone -U` is instantaneous and disk-space-free on modern file systems.  That's not true of a copy (which does work just fine too).